# Calling a method from overflowMenu?

Tags: java, android, menu, menuitem, android-menu

I have android code with a simple animation. Basically, on a tap down event, a button moves from top left to bottom right, while simultaneously enlarging. I have to methods, moveButton(); and moveButtonBack(); which are the methods that actually move the button using transitionManager. The problem is, when I call these methods from my

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { }
```

method, the method doesn't get called. I know it is not the fault of my method, because those work fine on tap down events. Please help me figure out why my moveButton() and moveButtonBack() methods aren't being called. I have already watched and read several tutorials about overFlowMenu's.

Here is the xml where I make the items for the menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"             tools:context=".MainActivity">


<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    app:showAsAction="never" />


<item
    android:id="@+id/MoveButtonExecution"
    android:orderInCategory = "2"
    app:showAsAction = "never"
    android:title = "Move button down!"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/MoveButtonBackExecution"
    android:orderInCategory = "3"
    app:showAsAction = "never"
    android:title = "Move button up!"
    />
</menu>
```

Here is the java code that should be calling the methods:

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    Button myButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.mybuttonid);

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.action_settings:
       item.setTitle("THIS DOES NOTHING");
            myButton.setText("No settings in animations");
            myButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

        case R.id.MoveButtonExecution:

            myButton.setText("moving");
            moveButton();


        case R.id.MoveButtonBackExecution:
            moveButtonBack();
            myButton.setText("movingback");
    }
```

If you need to see the methods moveButton and moveButtonBack, feel free to ask, but again, I am sure the methods are not the problem. Instead, I think the problem is in the java code where I **call** the methods. Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Shouldn't you have some `break`s in that `switch`?

Comment: Thank you so much for making me realize my small embarrassing mistake! With the breaks it runs fine. I still have one question then, shouldn't the last case have still executed without the breaks, as it would have been called last without any stops? Please let me know, thank you.

Comment: Yes the last case gets executed if any of the cases apply. That is why my comment was not as answer as I am not fully sure what is happening.

Comment: @Paul Boddington Okay, that's weird!  moveButtonBack() wasn't getting executed, even though it should have been. If you figure out why, let me know. Thank you! :)